# LEFT JOIN 3 tables while using an ON clause that references columns from the other two tables

Tags: sql, left-join, ms-access-2010

I'm using Access 2010 and I'm getting a "JOIN expression not supported" error when I try to save my query. Here's a simplified version of the query:

```
SELECT Sum(1) AS [Total People], Place.Name
FROM (([Person]
LEFT JOIN [Place] ON [Place].[Name] = [Person].[Place])
LEFT JOIN [Thing] ON [Thing].[Place] = [Place].[Name] 
  AND [Thing].[Owner] = [Person].[Name])
GROUP BY [Place].[Name]
HAVING [Thing].[Type] = "Food"
```

If I remove this from the Join statement the query can be saved.

```
AND [Thing].[Owner] = [Person].[Name]
```

Of course I would need to add the following HAVING statements in order for the query to return something that's functionally equivalent.

```
AND [Thing].[Owner] = [Person].[Name]
AND [Place].[Name] IS NOT NULL
AND [Thing].[Place] IS NOT NULL
```

The problem is that once I add these statements to my HAVING clause, I have to change my GROUP BY clause to also include these fields, and that changes the output from the desired result.

Am I trying to do the impossible, or am I wrong about something?

Comment: It Looks like you are on sql server 2008 r2, is this correct?

Comment: MS-Access 2010 I'll add this to the post.

Comment: Did you make this query using the designer? Sometimes there is a subtlety to the way Access wants joins constructed with multiple tables and it's best to just let it make the query. This is not a complicated query so it will be easy to drag and drop this stuff int eh designer.

Comment: You can try to move the and thing.owner = person.name to the where clause.

Comment: What about  "where [Thing].[Owner] = [Person].[Name]"

Comment: I didn't use the designer, the query in actuality is a bit more complex. And it includes a subquery, which access doesn't like to format. Access throws a syntax error when I try to include a WHERE statement.

Comment: I take back my previous statement. Adding a WHERE clause appears to have fixed the issue. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the brackets around your joins, add brackets around the join predicates.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/15c36745-f7a4-4926-9687-7161e5894468/join-expression-not-supported-error-caused-by-unbracketed-join-expression-comprising-string?forum=accessdev

```
SELECT Sum(1) AS [Total People], Place.Name
FROM [Person]
LEFT JOIN [Place] ON [Place].[Name] = [Person].[Place]
LEFT JOIN [Thing] ON ( [Thing].[Place] = [Place].[Name] 
                 AND [Thing].[Owner] = [Person].[Name])
GROUP BY [Place].[Name]
HAVING [Thing].[Type] = "Food"
```